# Office Web App Server 2013 .pdf Preview Error

Tags: 2013, owa

I have a SP2013 farm with Office Web Apps 2013 and all documents works fine with OWA but there is only one .pdf document that is not working.

I'm getting this error.

[image]

Also word is not displaying this file.

I can preview .pdf files on the browser except this. I realized that working .pdf files are not larger than 1 MB but this file is about 5.5 MB. Is there any .pdf file size limit at OWA?

I found this at ULS logs:

```
SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a ShareByLink request - missing access token
```

and this:

```
SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page:
```

Comment: have you tried to re upload the file? download it, delete from liobrary then upload again...looks like issue with file

Comment: Yes, I can download the file and display at local computer using Foxit Reader. Also copied to another document library and renamed it but still no chance to display at browser.

Comment: is it protected file? i would upload it to totally different site collection

Comment: No, it is not protected. I downloaded it to my local PC and then uploaded to a different site collection already, but still getting same error.